Почему Http запрос возвращает разный результат в браузере и в IDE?
Понимаю, вопрос вроде бы глупый, но что-то я не догоняю
Делаю небольшое API приложение по урокам
Есть запрос к сайту, который должен вернуть количество групп
https://javarush.com/api/1.0/rest/groups/count
В браузере возвращает 64
вот код метода, делающего запрос

    @Override
    public Integer getGroupCount(GroupCountRequestArgs requestArgs) {

    //не использую параметры http запроса (requestArgs) чтобы точно не было фильтра

    //1 вариант - возвращает в теле  27
        ResponseEntity<Integer> response = 
           restTemplate.exchange("https://javarush.com/api/1.0/rest/groups/count",HttpMethod.GET,
                null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Integer>() {
                });

    //2-й вариант, тоже возвращает 27
        var a = Unirest.get("https://javarush.com/api/1.0/rest/groups/count")
                .asObject(Integer.class);

        return null;
    }




Я в своём браузере вижу 27, непонятно откуда должно взяться 64

Добавил снимок браузера

И тем не менее в моём браузере всё ещё 27

М-магия. Что-то не так с моим браузером. Скачаю постман)


Что-то не так с моим браузером

С Вашим браузером все в порядке. Когда Вы выполняете запрос в браузере, и при этом залогинены на JavaRush, в запрос добавляются куки - в этом случае сервис действительно отправляет 64, а не 27.

В блоге они пишут:

Ради интереса посмотрите, что будет, если поставить filter = MY в браузере, где вы залогинены в Javarush и не залогинены.

Что уже как-бы намекает...)
